# Get the reference path of unique Item Id in Firebase using Ionic

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have made a function to send data to firebase using UID. The data appears in firebase with UID and item ID. I'm able to retrieve the data when if the user is logged in but i'm getting confused on how to get the path of a specific node child of an item which has a unique auto generated ID.

```js
  // Data stored in firebase

  "profiles" : {
  // UID
    "SUFbOOK4XvPNIaQqIjJ2ey6ziDF3"  : {
    //Item ID
      "-M54AgiUdxYEmu20Yau0" : {

      //childs
        "eau" : "111111",
        "edan" : "22222",
        "image" : "0625594",
        "nom" : "hello",
        "prenom" : "world",
        "profession" : "Dev",
        "solde" : "100000",
        "telephone" : "06255444794"
      }
    }
```

Here is the path reference of this database until userID.

```js
this.reference = firebase.database().ref('profiles/'+this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid);
```

And Here is the function to send data to Firebase

```js
create(nom,telephone,edan,prenom,profession,eau,solde){

    this.imageName = telephone;
    let loading = this.load.create({
      content: 'Veuillez patienter ...'
    });
    loading.present();
    setTimeout(() => {
      loading.dismiss();
      this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
      this.af.list(`profiles/${auth.uid}`).push({
        nom: nom,
        edan: edan,
        eau: eau,
        prenom: prenom,
        profession: profession,
        telephone: telephone,
        solde: solde,
        image:this.imageName,

      }).then (() => 
      this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage')
      )
      })
    }, 2500);
    this.upload()
  }
```

How can I get the reference path of the unique item Id of a list in Firebase with UID?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
reference.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key); // "SUFbOOK4XvPNIaQqIjJ2ey6ziDF3"
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key); // "-M54AgiUdxYEmu20Yau0"
    console.log(child.val().nom); // "hello"
    child.child("nom").ref.update("world");
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Instead of just view this values with console.log, how can I use child.key in a reference path? That's actually the step I'm stuck on.